# Locally defined Double array makes the program crash

Tags: c++, arrays, crash

I have the following variables defined locally in a function member of a class in C++:

```
    double coeff, mincoeff, minratio,
           equality[100][5000],
           tableau[51][5052],
           x[50][100];
```

When running the program crashes. When I comment out `equality` array it works but If I do not comment it out, it make the program crashes. It is not true for `tableau` array and it always works with 'tableau' array and without 'equality' array. I saw a post to use `malloc()` function to assign space dynamically like :

`double *equality;
equality = malloc(500000*sizeof(double));`

But it gives me an error of no conversion from `void*` to `double*`. Is there another way?

Comment: And what's the error message that appears when the program crashes? It should tell you what went wrong.

Comment: Yes, there is another way: `std::vector`.

Comment: `(100 * 5000 + 51 * 5052 + 50 * 100) * sizeof(double) == bad_times_for_your_stack`

Comment: @ MrEricSir It actually a programming environment for OMNet++, the network simulator. I think it uses Eclips software. I does not say anything special. Just says program finished with error. I am positive it is from this variable declaration since everything else is commented out.

Comment: @Masoud Just what the site's name indicates :). Your stack is too small.

Comment: @user657267 gave a good hint.  More explicitly, the 4 megs of stack space requested with half a million eight-byte doubles is your problem.  It's just way too big.  The post about using heap memory (the malloc suggestion) was correct or at least reasonable.  You probably want to use 'new double[the-number-of-doubles]' and do not forget to delete[] that result later.

Comment: it is maybe the huge size of array equality makes the program crashes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

allocate eqaulity on the heap and when you're done with it free memory:

```
int main()
{

    double** equality = new double* [100];
    for(int i(0); i < 100; i++)
        equality[i] = new double[5000];

    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        delete[] equality[i];
    delete[] equality;

    equality = NULL;


    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Like @user657267 have mentioned, you are asking 4MB of continuous chunk of memory for equality. Best thing to do here is to ask for the memory dynamically.

```
double **equality = new (nothrow) double*[100]; //Or do exception check to make sure you have enough memory
if (equality!=nullptr)
{
  for(int i(0); i < 100; i++) 
  {
    equality[i] = new (nothrow) double[5000]; //Again or do exception check to handle exception if it cannot get asked memory.
    if (equality[i] == nullptr)
    {
      //Handle the situation where memory could not be allocated
      ...
    }
  }
}
else
{
  //Handle not being able to allocate memory
}
```

Regarding c-style malloc (works with C++ as well), you have to cast to correct data type like following:

```
double *equality;
equality = (double*) malloc(500000*sizeof(double));
```

Note: do not forget to free what you have allocated.